# download file using samba

Tags: ubuntu-9.04, samba, file-download

i have a LAN network..
i want download some file at another PC(windows).
i will download that file from my PC (linux ubuntu).
someone tell me that i better use samba..
can you tell how to download files from another PC using samba?

Comment: If this is an occasional need, then the easiest option is to copy the file to a usb thumb drive or use a cloud service like Google docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1.  Make sure the Windows version is sharing the file with appropriate permissions.

Step 2. (Gnome version) Click Places/Network and navigate to the Windows PC.  Provide authentication if necessary.  Find the file. Drag and drop back to Ubuntu PC.

Step 3.  Go to SuperUser.Com and mark this as "answered"  :-)

Hotei

PS: In your case Samba is required only if going from Ubuntu back to Windows.  I also use it for Ubuntu to Ubuntu or other *Unix flavors.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be best looking at [one](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=202605) or [two](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=26438&highlight=samba+howto) Samba on Ubuntu tutorials, then coming back with more specific questions if they don't manage to get you up and running.